# Regex expression for pulling string from the url

Tags: javascript, regex

So say I have a url such as: https://somevalue.stackoverflow.edu

How would I write a js regex expression to extract the 'somevalue' string from the url? The 'somevalue' string can be dynamic so I can't slice the index values

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a regex to do this:

```js
myvar = "https://somevalue.stackoverflow.edu"
extracted = myvar.split("/")[2].split(".")[0]
```